# Removing file using name contains in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, if-statement, io, automation

I have written the below code to keep a file that matches the passed in name and removes the rest of the files in the folder.

```
def removeFiles2(path, namePart)
  aft_logger=AFTLogger.new

  Dir[path+'/*'].each do |fname|
    break if !(fname.include? namePart)
          else File.delete(fname)
          end
  end
end
end
```

But I am getting the below error.

```
Operation not permitted - Operation not permitted - //CSLK-CISP-81-01/jboss/server/TeamCI_CEPHEUS_OR_R81_Spider_110/home/RoSModule/XML/In/Error: 
Operation not permitted - Operation not permitted - //CSLK-CISP-81-
01/jboss/server/TeamCI_CEPHEUS_OR_R81_Spider_110/home/RoSModule/XML/In/Error tempDevMode.rb line 37 in function test
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is that you actual code? It would raise a _syntax error_ because of the modifier `if-else` construct (there's no such thing). You can write `break if condition` but not `break if condition else ...`

Comment: @Stefan you missed misaligned `end` :) It’s actually `break (if .. else .. end)`.

Comment: Yeah, that break is super confusing :) And it definitely is a syntax error (as written, without explicit parentheses around if/else)

Comment: @mayooran you could write `break unless fname.include? namePart` and on the next line `File.delete(fname)`, i.e. without the `else` and the `end`

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work. just try it out

```
def removeFiles(path, namePart)

Dir[path+'/*'].each do |fname|
    if fname.include? namePart
     //just print something you want

    else  
      File.delete(fname)
  end
 end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just delete all the files unless the files basename matches the file you want to exclude

```rb
def remove_files(path, exclude)
  Dir.glob("#{path}/*").each do |file|
    File.delete(file) unless File.basename(file).include?(exclude)
  end
end
```